# point to <form> in html

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have started a new laravel project(BTW I am new to laravel) and I am using the javascript list-group from bootstrap. So when I click on an item in a group it toggles the respective content. What I want to do is instead of inserting the actual HTML of the content there, I want to point it to another PHP file or something similar that contains the content code so all my files remain clean and easy to program. Hope U expressed my query properly, Cheers!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to point to another php file, why don't you just put the path to the php file that you want inside <a href="#yourpath"> tag ?

Answer (score 1):

As TheUnKnown mentioned in the comment, you can replace your `#link` hrefs with real urls. Also remove the `data-toggle` attribute from the links. For example:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" href="/home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" href="/profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" href="/messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" href="/settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
```